# Should I use XML in my c++ game

Tags: c++, xml

Is XML something required to use in modern games?  Sense I'm trying to make game that will be programmed like a professional programmer did it, So should i use XML in my game or it is just an optional thing, Why and Why not?

Comment: All modern games and applications have some XML files

Comment: No, not all. That's a gross generalisation. I know of many large scale projects which do not use XML at all.

Comment: What kind of data? For keeping data is a very abstract purpose... you should not simply use it just because others use it...

Comment: Unreal Engine 3 is one of the largest game engines.. and it doesn't use xml...

Comment: I'm not user for kinda of data, but it just seems so important

Comment: Write it in assembly, it's cooler ;)

Comment: @ruslik: you have an incredible sense of satire :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using XML if it solves your problem. There's nothing wrong with *not* using XML if it isn't the best option for solving your problem.

If you want to store data in an a format which is easy to query, then XML is not a bad option. If you're look for space efficiency, XML is not a good option. If you are looking for cross-platform features, XML is a no-brainer compared to binary formats.

JSON is another option which is very simple and very lightweight.

In short, it depends on your requirements. If you want more direction you'll have to give more information.

Comment: XML is like violence.  If it doesn't solve your problem you aren't using enough of it.   j/k.

Comment: Not sure I agree about "easy to query", unless your data is document-oriented. For record-based data, CSV or YAML is just as easy as XML. However I agree about portability (cross-platform) - XML is designed as a data interchange format.

Comment: You think "querying" CSV/YAML is easier than using Xpath to query XML? Can I see some proof of how "easy" it is?

Answer (score 1):

Use whatever works for you. Don't judge your tools based on whether something is considered "uncool". If it works for you and helps you create maintainable and flexible code and data, use it.

Now specifically for XML - that's definitely a format that is widely used and has libraries for virtually every platform. I've worked on a recent Xbox 360 and PlayStation 3 title that made use of XML.